# method in the child class redefined different from the parent class gives error (strict standards)

Tags: php, inheritance, methods

I'm getting this error:

> Declaration of PayPal::raiseError()
>   should be compatible with that of
>   PEAR::raiseError()

These are PEAR::raiseError() and PayPal::raiseError() respectively:

```
function &raiseError($message = null,
                     $code = null,
                     $mode = null,
                     $options = null,
                     $userinfo = null,
                     $error_class = null,
                     $skipmsg = false)
{


class PayPal extends PEAR
{
    function raiseError($message, $code = null)
    {
        return parent::raiseError($message, $code, null, null, null, 'PayPal_Error');
    }
```

Any way to make it work without modifying the definitions?

I read [here](http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=79211) about the order the class are loaded. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the order in which classes are loaded. Since `PayPal` extends `PEAR`, any function that would take a `PEAR` object as parameter actually might be given a `PayPal` object. And since the `PEAR` method `raiseError()` allows up to seven parameters, the `PayPal` method should also allow at least up to seven parameters.

The best solution would be to refactor `raiseError()` in `PayPal`:

```
function raiseError($message = null,
                    $code = null,
                    $mode = null,
                    $options = null,
                    $userinfo = null,
                    $error_class = null,
                    $skipmsg = false)
{
    return parent::raiseError($message, $code, $mode, $options,
                              $userinfo, 'PayPal_Error', $skipmsg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!, the only detail you forgot is the "&" before the name of the method. Without that the error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The signature (parameters) of the child class method need to be the same as the parent method. This is because PHP does not allow overloading functions with varying parameter counts or types.

You could always just rename your `raiseError` method to something different, like `raiseErrorWrapper` to sidestep this issue.